# C# not drop a line in text box when the text is longer than the box width

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am writing an app in c# with windows form (.net 3.5),
I am using a text box and I want to know if there is a way that when the user inserts text to the text box and the text is longer then the box width, it will not drop a line, It will Continue in the same line.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set text box property WordWrap to false.